# Solving $\frac{dy}{dx} = ae^{-bx} - cy(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would you solve an equation in the form

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = ae^{-bx} - cy(x) $$

where $a, b, c$ are just constants. My ultimate goal is to find $y(x)$ without the derivative in there.

My confusion comes from the fact that the right hand side has both $y(x)$ and $x$ itself in it. I tried using the integrating factor method and it gets me a similar form of solution that I want, but not completely. So is this the method I should be using or is there another that works for this type of equation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You can use [Method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) here.  Incidentally, it's better not to use $*$ for "ordinary" multiplication in the context of differential equations: it can be confused with [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Comment: @user539887 No big reason for MoUC here.

Comment: If your confusion comes from the fact that the right hand side has both $y(x)$ and $x$ itself in it , put the $y(x)$ term on the left side : $$\frac{dy}{dx}+cy(x) = ae^{-bx}  $$

Answer (score 1):

$$y'+cy = ae^{-bx} \tag 1$$
Solving with the variation of parameter method :

First, solve the associated homogeneous ODE 
$$\quad y'+cy = 0 \tag 2$$
The solution is :
$$y=\lambda e^{-cx}$$
where $\lambda$ is a constant with respect to $x$.

Second, apply the method of variation of parameter. This means that the constant $\lambda$ is now considered as a function of $x$.

$y=\lambda(x) e^{-cx}$ is no longer solution of Eq.$(2)$, but will be solution of Eq.$(1)$ :

$y'=\lambda'e^{-cx}-c\lambda e^{-cx}\quad$ Putting it into Eq.$(1)$ :
$$y'+cy = ae^{-bx}=(\lambda'e^{-cx}-c\lambda e^{-cx})+c(\lambda e^{-cx})$$
$$ae^{-bx}=\lambda'e^{-cx}$$
$$\lambda'=ae^{(c-b)x}$$
$$\lambda=\frac{a}{c-b}e^{(c-b)x}+C$$
$y=\left(\frac{a}{c-b}e^{(c-b)x}+C \right) e^{-cx}$
$$y(x)=\frac{a}{c-b}e^{-bx}+Ce^{-cx}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

It is :

$$y'(x) + cy(x) = ae^{-bx}$$

Find an integrating factor $\mu$ as

$$\mu(x) = \exp\left( \int c\mathrm{d}x\right) = e^{cx}$$

and multiply both sides of the ODE with it. It yields :

$$e^{cx}y'(x) + ce^{cx}y(x) = ae^{cx-bx} $$

Now, observe that :

$$e^{cx}y'(x) + cy(x) = \Big( e^{cx}y(x) \Big)'$$

Can you finish ?

Comment: Really $(e^{cx} y(x) y)'$?

Comment: @user539887 It was a typo, thanks for pointing out and you can take a step back before downvoting :)